# Событие нажатия на колесо мыши Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть простая ссылка типа

```
<div id="link">
   <a href="/somePage/someMethod?argument=2">Click here</a>
</div>
```

Можно ли с помощью jquery отловить событие нажатия на колесико мыши на элементе $("#link")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого достаточно лишь отловить событие `mousedown`, а затем в коллбэке проверить, что свойство `which` объекта `event` равняется `2`.

```js
document.querySelector("#link").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 2) {
       console.log("Middle");
    }
});

// JQuery, если принципиально

$("#link").on("mousedown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 2) {
       console.log("Middle");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Правда, не знаю, как этот код поведет себя, например, на компьютерах Apple, где средней клавиши мыши вообще нет.

Можно еще проверить свойство `button`. Но там за среднюю кнопку мыши отвечает значение `1`, а не `2`, как у `which`.

Comment: Про Apple я, если что, к тому написал, что есть вероятность того, что значения кнопок "сместятся", и `2` станет равно правой кнопке, например, что может привести неприятные неожиданности.

Comment: И еще кое-что. Если эту проверку вы используете, чтобы проверить, открывается ли ссылка в другую вкладку, то, мне кажется, лучше использовать какой-нибудь другой способ.

Answer (score -2):

[Ссылка](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) на документацию...

```js
$("#link").mousedown(function() {
console.log(event.which);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="link">
  <a href="/somePage/someMethod?argument=2">Click here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: речь в  вопросе, очевидно, идет о том, чтобы отделить клики кнопок от колеса.

Comment: @teran детский сад какой-то... Речь от тем что бы отловить, а как еще и где и почему, отчего, сколько и куда....  Решит сам владелец вопроса, а не я....  Спросил как отловить, вот пример...))))

Comment: вопрос как отловить клик средней кнопки, именно средней, а не любой из трех. Если вас спросят как отловить нажатия enter на клавиатуре, вы голый `keydown` приведет что ли?

Comment: @teran, Не пойму, чего так нервничать....)))   Ну поставил минус и все... Чего меня уму разуму учить?))  Тут некоторое время назад, был разговор, что не рыбу надо человеку давать а удочку...)))

Comment: @Air было было :)

Comment: @Даниил, ))))))  видишь как тут весело???

Comment: @Air весело и местами очень не понятно)

Comment: @Даниил  не могу не сгласиться...